# @Asynchronous method is blocking

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb

In a @Stateless enterprise bean I’ve a method which does some work which takes a long time. So I’m trying to call this method asynchronously. To achieve that I’ve added a @Asynchronous to this method. 
So far so good.
In a pretty normal @GET method where the result would be a 200-OK I call the above mentioned async method. What I ‘ve expected is that the @GET method calls the async method, returns back with the 200-OK result and the async method gets executed in background (concurrent). But that’s actually not what happens. In my case the async method blocks the @GET method.

Why is my async method blocking? And how can I achiev a non-blocking call?

Comment: Your exprectations are wrong are. `@Async` runs the request on a different threads, rather than an HTTP worker, but it doesn't make the client async. For that you need to do some more work. For example, you could write `202 Accepted` _before_ invoking the long running process, and then continue writing content to the stream as and when its available. This still won't work out of the box however. An HTTP request is an inherently _synchronous_ activity for a browser.

Comment: Okay. My plan was it to always return a 200 OK immediately, then do the work and then update my UI using a websocket connection. So, how can I invoke a method concurrent? Using a thread pool? Any tutorials, ideas? Thank you!

Comment: That's _far_ too broad. But yes, you need to manually hand off processing and let the request finish. Returning a `202` with a `Location` header of e.g. a websocket end point would then allow the client to connect and monitor progress.

Comment: Could manage it by using the ManagedThreadFactory. Thank you for your advices.